# Given $B\mapsto\operatorname{det}(A)^{-1} \operatorname{det}(A B)$, conlude that $\operatorname{det}(A B)=\operatorname{det}(A) \operatorname{det}(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra

For any $A \in \mathbb{k}^{n \times n}$, prove that $B \in \mathbb{k}^{n \times n} \mapsto \operatorname{det}(A)^{-1} \operatorname{det}(A B)$ is an $n$-multilinear alternating form on the space of columns, which evaluates to 1 on the identity matrix. Conclude that $\operatorname{det}(A B)=\operatorname{det}(A) \operatorname{det}(B)$.

I was able to prove the first part by proving that if I change a column, $r$, of B for $\alpha b_r+v$, then the column $r$ of $AB'$ is $\alpha(AB)_r+Av$. Then I used the multilinear properties of the determinant.

Similarly, if I swap two columns of $B$, $AB'$ will also have those same columns swapped so once again I can use the alternated properties of the determinant.

The identity part was pretty straight forward since $det(A)^{-1}det(AI)=det(A)^{-1}det(A)=1$.

How do I proceed to prove that $\operatorname{det}(A B)=\operatorname{det}(A) \operatorname{det}(B)$?

Comment: The point is that det is the *unique* alternating multilinear function which evaluates to $1$ on the identity matrix.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin ohhh I see, I reply my own question, do you think that conclusion is sufficient?

Comment: Yes, that’s fine.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the determinant is the unique alternating multilinear function which evaluates to $1$ on the identity matrix. Let's call our function $f$, then since $f(I)=1$, $f$ must be the determinant function.

So we have $f(B)=\operatorname{det}(A)^{-1} \operatorname{det}(A B)=\operatorname{det}(B)$. Multiplying by $\operatorname{det}(A)$ by both sides,
$$\operatorname{det}(A B)=\operatorname{det}(A)\operatorname{det}(B).$$